# ¿Por que no se me visualiza los cambios subidos a mi repositorio remoto?

Tags: android-studio, git, github, git-push, repositorio

Realice unos cambios en mi proyecto de Android Studio y tras eso, escribí los comandos:

```sh
 $ git init
 $ git status 
 $ git add .
 $ git commit -m ""
 $ git push origin master
```

Revise si se habían subido correctamente al repositorio remoto pero no se visualizaban así que use el comando

```
$ git log
```

Y solo se me reflejaba unos cambios que tenía de hace un tiempo ya.

Me gustaría saber por que si cuando realice los **git** no me apareció ningún error.

Pero al volverlos a realizarlo me salió:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Este error suele dar cuando tienes un proyecto en un directorio que es ya parte de otro proyecto. Asegúrate de que en AndroidStudioProjects no hay un directorio `.git`

Comment: Tengo archivos .gitignore solo .git no. Android Studio tiene para hacer commit y todo directamente pero no se como usarlo, ya que siempre que las uso me dan problemas por eso siempro lo hago mediante terminal. Pero no se hacer que vaya ahora a procedimiento remoto

Comment: @Rosa como indica Pablo, debes tener un directorio .git en la raiz de tu proyecto pero al parecer tienes en algún subdirectorio otro directorio .git, este debe ser eliminado, agregué respuesta.

Comment: Si me puse a buscar en todo y tal como dice tenía varios .git creado en nuevas carpetas que cree x error los elimine pero me sigue sin dejar subirlo. Bueno sale como si estuviera subido pero cuando lo intentó visualizar en repositorio remoto me sigue sin salir.

Answer (score 0):

La rama principal en git ahora se llama main, es posible que al hacer el push hayas creado sin querer una nueva rama llamada "master" y por eso no te aparece. prueba a usar `git branch` para comprobar esto.

Comment: Si comprobé lo de la rama y solo me sale una rama master

Answer (score 0):

El error :

> error: 'adventureTravel/' does not have a commit checked out
>
> fatal: ading filesfailed

Indica que en algún subdirectorio puedes tener un directorio .git, debes eliminarlo.

Puedes buscar los subdirectorios que contenga directorio '.git' en tu proyecto y que estén ocasionando este problema, estando dentro del directorio de tu proyecto:

```
find ./ -name '.git'
```

y puedes eliminar el directorio '.git' no necesario de esta forma:

```
rm -r directorioaeliminar/.git/
```